# Difference between Java's `Double.MIN_NORMAL` and `Double.MIN_VALUE`?

Tags: java, ieee-754

What's the difference between [`Double.MIN_NORMAL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_NORMAL) (introduced in Java 1.6) and [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE)?

Comment: I've written an IEEE 754 subnormal tutorial that might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number/53203428#53203428

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [IEEE specification of floating point representation](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_math.html):

> *For the single format, the difference between a normal number and a subnormal number is that the leading bit of the significand (the bit to left of the binary point) of a normal number is 1, whereas the leading bit of the significand of a subnormal number is 0. Single-format subnormal numbers were called single-format denormalized numbers in IEEE Standard 754.*

In other words, `Double.MIN_NORMAL` is the smallest possible number you can represent, provided that you have a 1 in front of the binary point (what is referred to as decimal point in a decimal system). While `Double.MIN_VALUE` is basically the smallest number you can represent without this constraint.

Answer (score 14):

IEEE-754 binary64 format:

```
s_eee_eeee_eeee_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm_mmmm
```

(1 `s`; 3×4−1 =11 `e`s; 64−3×4 =52 `m`s)

, and its algorithm:

- If `e >000_0000_0000` and `<111_1111_1111`: interpret as `(-1)`<sup>s</sup> ×2<sup>e−balancer:1023</sup> ×`(`base:1 +m×2<sup>−sub-one-pusher:52</sup>`)`. (These are the normal numbers.)
- If `e =000_0000_0000`: do the same (as line above) except `base:1` is `base:0`, and `e` is `e +1`. (These are the subnormal numbers, except for zero which is neither subnormal/normal.)
- If `e =111_1111_1111` and `m =0000...0000`: interpret as `(-1)`<sup>s</sup> × infinity.
- If `e =111_1111_1111` and `m <>0000...0000`: interpret as NaN. (Btwbtw: therefore there're 2× `(`2<sup>52</sup> −1`)` different bit representations for NaN, cf [#Quiet NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Quiet_NaN) &[`doubleToRawLongBits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)).)

Thus:

- The smallest of its possible positive numbers is `0_000_0000_0000_0000_..._0001` ([`Double.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) (also .NET's [`Double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2))) (a subnormal number).
- The smallest of its possible positive normal numbers is `0_000_0000_0001_0000_..._0000` ([`Double.MIN_NORMAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_NORMAL)).

---

**Appendix:**

`MIN_VALUE` computation:

(-1)<sup>s:0</sup> ×2<sup>(e:0+1)−balancer:1023</sup> ×(base:0 +m:1 ×2<sup>−sub-one-pusher:52</sup>)

= 1 ×2<sup>−1022</sup> ×2<sup>−52</sup>

= 2<sup>−1074</sup> ([~4.94 × 10<sup>−324</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E-1074))

, and `MIN_NORMAL` computation:

(-1)<sup>s:0</sup> ×2<sup>e:1 −balancer:1023</sup> ×(base:1 +m:0 ×2<sup>−sub-one-pusher:52</sup>)

= 1 ×2<sup>−1022</sup> ×1

= 2<sup>−1022</sup> ([~2.225 × 10<sup>−308</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E-1022))

Comment: I think you want `2^{1 + 52} - 2` for the number of NaN bit patterns.

Comment: And a nitpick: zero isn't a subnormal, so the "These are the subnormal numbers." statement isn't quite accurate.  How about "These are the subnormal numbers and zeros." instead?

Comment: Well, there are two cases where `m == 0`: one with `s == 0`, and one with `s == 1`.  Put another way, for a NaN bit pattern, there are `2` possibilities for `s`, only one for `e`, and `2^52 - 1` for `m`; multiplying gives `2 * (2^52 - 1) = 2^53 - 2` overall possibilities.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, why isn't zero subnormal? Looks like it fits the definition to me: it has a 0 in front of the binary point, and the exponent bits are all zero.

Comment: @aioobe Which definition are you looking at? IEEE 754's definitions section says: "2.1.51 subnormal number: In a particular format, a non-zero floating-point number with magnitude less than the magnitude of that format’s smallest normal number. [...].", and also in the definition of "normal number" (2.1.38): "In this standard, zero is neither normal nor subnormal."

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, the explanation will consider just the positive numbers.

The maximum spacing between two **adjacent normalized floating point numbers** 'x1' and 'x2' is `2 * epsilon * x1` (the normalized floating point numbers are not evenly spaced, they are logarithmically spaced). That means, that when a **real number** (i.e. the "mathematical" number) is rounded to a floating point number, the maximum **relative error** is `epsilon`, which is a constant called machine epsilon or [unit roundoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), and for double precision it has the value 2^-52 (approximate value 2.22e-16).

The floating point numbers smaller than `Double.MIN_NORMAL` are called subnormals, and they are evenly filling the gap between 0 and `Double.MIN_NORMAL`. That means that the computations involving subnormals can lead to less accurate results. Using subnormals allows a calculation to lose precision more slowly when the result is small.