# Difference between Float.MIN_VALUE and Float.MIN_NORMAL?

Tags: java, numbers, floating-point, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference among Double.MIN_NORMAL and Double.MIN_VALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728309/difference-among-double-min-normal-and-double-min-value)

1) Can some one pls explain to me what the difference is between MIN_NORMAL and MIN_VALUE?

```
System.out.println(Float.MIN_NORMAL);
System.out.println(Float.MIN_VALUE);
```

2) Also, why does still still print 1.0?

```
float f = Float.MIN_NORMAL + 1.0f;
System.out.println(f);

double d = Float.MIN_NORMAL + 1.0f;
System.out.println(d);
```

Output:

```
1.17549435E-38
1.4E-45
1.0
1.0
```

Comment: FP conversions: http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/flt/dtof.html and  http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/flt/dtof.html

Comment: Another good intro (Should've read it before posting) http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/91float and this http://tfinley.net/notes/cps104/floating.html

Comment: Some finishing notes - http://mindprod.com/jgloss/floatingpoint.html

Comment: This is Java, I take it? This may be a stupid question, but what is the definition of MIN_NORMAL in terms of C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer for the first question is in the duplicate.

The answer for the second question is:

Both Floats and Doubles do not have infinite precision. You can conveniently think they have *around* 16 digits of precision. Anything past that and you are going to have rounding errors and truncation.

So, 1.0e0 + 1e-38 is going to lack precision to do anything except for end with 1.0e0 due to truncating the extra precision.

Really, like the rest of the answer, it requires an understanding of how floating point numbers in IEEE format are actually added in binary. The basic idea is that the non-sign-and-exponent portion of the binary, floating point number is shifted in the IEEE-754 unit on the CPU (80 bits wide on Intel, which means there is always truncation at the end of the calculation) to represent its real number. In decimal this would look like this:

```
Digit: 1 234567890123456
Value: 1.0000000000000000000000000000...0000
Value: 0.0000000000000000000000000000...0001
```

After the add is processed, it is practically:

```
Digit: 1 234567890123456
Value: 1.0000000000000000000000000000...0001
```

So, with it in mind that the value truncates around the 16 digit mark (in decimal, it's exactly 22 *binary* digits in a 32-bit float, and 51 *binary* digits in a 64-bit double, ignoring the very important fact that the leading 1 is shifted (with respect to the exponent) and assumed (effectively compressing 23 binary digits into 22 for 32-bit and 52 to 51 for 64-bit); this is a very interesting point, but one you should read more detailed examples, such as [here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) for those details).

Truncated:

```
Digit: 1 234567890123456
Value: 1.00000000000000000000
```

Note the really small decimal portion is truncated, thus leaving 1.

Here is a good page that I use whenever I have issues thinking about the actual representation in memory: [Decimal to 32-bit IEEE-754 format](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html). In the site, there are links for 64-bit as well and going in reverse.