# How to get double value using libpq from Postgres

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I am using `libpq` to connect to Postgres on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015, PostgreSQL9.4

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE real_data (
  plane_id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  timestamp integer NOT NULL,
  data1 double precision
);

INSERT INTO real_data VALUES ('100001', '14987654', 635.28938)
```

And when I get it out `char* data1 = PQgetvalue(res, row,2);`,  `data1` is `"635.28938"` in the watch, and if I convert it to double with `atof`, `double d_value = atof(data1)`, `d_value` is `635.28938000000000005`. It's not exactly the same.

I found this question on SO: [How to get the double value using libpq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504043/how-to-get-the-double-value-using-libpq) , but I don't think I can follow it since I have a ascii string representing the original double in `data1`.

How can I get an accurate double number from Postgres?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use exact datatype `DECIMAL/NUMERIC`

Comment: @lad2025 I tried `NUMERIC (15, 8)`, it's the same. I haven't try `DECIMAL` yet.

Comment: The result of `atof` followed by `printf` is independant of libpq or postgres. What you see is just an expected imprecision in a decimal representation of IEEE double. See for example [decimal number and exact representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068434)

Comment: @DanielVérité Yes, I understand it has nothing to do with libpq/postgres. What I'd like to know is how to get an exact double value from postgres. What I could find is to use PQgetValue, but it gives me an ascii string of the double value ( which I thought it would be a binary value ). So I had to convert it with atof, from which I get a double value with a tiny difference. Is there a way I could get an exact double number out of Postgres directly?

Comment: @larryzhao: there's no way because the imprecision comes from the `double` datatype itself, both in C/C++ and in SQL. If you requested a binary representation (it's possible, see `PQexecParams`) it wouldn't change that fact.