# Minimum evaluatable scientific value?

Tags: r

Does `R` store the smallest possibly representable scientific value?

To clarify: on my current machine:

```
>1e-300
[1] 1e-300
```

While

```
>1e-400
[1] 0
```

Through trial and error I know it is somewhere around the `e-324` mark on my  machine (where it also starts losing precision).

```
>1e-324
[1] 0
>5e-324
[1] 4.940656e-324
```

I've searched through the `.Machine` list and none of the values it stores contain either the value, or the exponent I'm looking for.

**Edit:**

Linked threads on the side indicate that this should be `.Machine$double.eps`, which is `2.220446e-16`. Clearly this is no longer the case?

Comment: So you're going to limit "size" to the quantum foam level? Or would you like to go smaller?  I hearby declare 2^(-(factorial(googolplex))) to be of scientific interest!   Anyway, seriously, take a look at `gmp` before asking for max/min size of numbers.

Comment: If you must know, I'm attempting to render a manhattan plot of -log10 p-values for covariates in my data. So for genes on the Y chromosome, obviously, the p-values are 0. `plot` doesn't like `Inf` in its ylim, so I want I'm substituting 0s for the "minimum".

Comment: There are estimated `10^80` atoms in the observable universe. Lets just ignore all numbers larger than that too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smallest normalised is `double.xmin`, as described in this [page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html). The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) entry is very interesting and has the subnormal limit which is `2^-1074`, which is approximately `4.9406564584124654 x 10^-324` (from Wikipedia as Ben Bolker mentioned in the comments). Your output in R is matching this value.

`double.epsilon` is not what you think. It is the smallest number you can add to 1 such as you obtain a number which will be not recognised as 1.

I suggest you read about how the double are stored in memory and the basics of double operations. Once you understand how a double is stored the lower limit is obvious.

Comment: This seems to only hold true for addition and subtraction:
`> 5e-320 + 2.225074e-308;
[1] 2.225074e-308`
While ordering, multiplication, and division work for smaller values:
`> 5e-310/2;
[1] 2.5e-310;
> 5e-310*2;
[1] 1e-309;
> 5e-310 < 5e-309;
[1] TRUE;
`

Comment: This is the smallest normalised value. I added a link to Wikipedia, which contains the smallest subnormalised value. Read also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Comment: Thanks! I'm confused why `R`'s limit seems to be in between the normal and subnormal limits. `4.940656e-324` seems to be the minimum value. anything below 8e-324 evaluates to that number, where `2.47e-324` is approximately the point where it evaluates to 0.

Comment: From `?.Machine`: `Note that on most platforms smaller positive values than ‘.Machine$double.xmin’ can occur.  On a typical R platform the smallest positive double is about ‘5e-324’.` (This doesn't say *why*, exactly, but it does document the phenomenon.)

Comment: The number you quote `4.940656e-324` is exactly `2^(-1074)`, as pointed out in the wiki link in the answer ...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @BenBolker, my brain skipped over the `2^` part and instead interpreted it as `e-1074`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer remains correct for base `R`, but using the package [`Rmpfr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) enables arbitrary precision. Example:

First, note issue in base `R`:

```
> p <- c("5e-600","2e-324","3e-324","4e-324", "5e-324","6e-324","7.1e-324","8e-324")
> as.numeric(p)
[1]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 4.940656e-324 4.940656e-324 4.940656e-324 4.940656e-324
[7] 4.940656e-324 9.881313e-324
```

Observe that as we near the limit the precision is an issue and all values are `4.940656e-324`.

Now use `mpfr` function from 'Rmpfr` package to cast the strings as floats:

```
> library(Rmpfr)
> .N <- function(.) mpfr(., precBits = 20)
> .N(p)
8 'mpfr' numbers of precision  20   bits 
[1] 5.0000007e-600   2.00000e-324 2.9999979e-324   4.00000e-324 4.9999966e-324 5.9999959e-324
[7]   7.09999e-324   8.00000e-324
```

Comment: And if you want even bigger numbers you can use the `Brobdingnag` package (i.e. my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r/22467504#22467504). It seems every few years I forget then relearn the issues with floating point numbers through stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks @ScottRitchie. Do you know if `Brobdingnag` works with very small numbers. From package doc, seems that it works only for very large numbers; however,  seems like both should work.

Comment: I've just tried to play around a bit, and it seems to lose the negative in the exponent for extremely small numbers, so I think the answer is no.