# Calculate sum ((v/u) * (d^a)) ^ (1/a) for large d and a

Tags: r, floating-point, precision

In R, I need to calculate `sum((v/u) * (d^a))^(1/a)` (see below) when `d` can be from 0 up to 10000 and `a` may be from 0 to 100. However, this overflows to `Inf`. `v/u` is dimensionless, as is `a`. I therefore assume that the result is on the same scale as `d`.

Is there a way to avoid the overflow in this calculation, either by some clever math, built-in functions, or by auto-scaling `d`, and then re-scaling the result without losing precision?

```
> N <- 200
> a <- 100
> v <- runif(N, min=1, max=20)
> u <- sum(v)
> d <- runif(N, min=1, max=8000)
> sum((v/u) * (d^a))^(1/a)
[1] Inf
```

[image]

Comment: "`a` may be from 0 to 100." and code has `1/a`?  To avoid that overflow, treat `a==0` as a special case.  Not certain what the return value should be other than some infinity.

Comment: @chux but here OP defined `a <- 100`. So, that's not the problem. But `d` can be between 1 and 8000 which to the power of 100 can be a very large number. That's the issue I think. Any `d >= 1210` to the power 100 will be `Inf`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r

Comment: @chux Right, `a == 0` needs to caught earlier on. The overflow to `Inf` happens for large `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you look for, but you can rescale your `d` vector

```
N <- 200
a <- 100
v <- runif(N, min=1, max=20)
u <- sum(v)
d <- runif(N, min=1, max=8000)
D <- max(d)
D*sum((v/u) * ((d/D)^a))^(1/a) 
[1] 7721.741
```

Here I used the maximum value, but you can get better results as long as `D` is large enough to avoid `(d/D)^a` reaching computer infinity.

The point is, if you choose `D` too small your sum is ruined because you get `Inf` in a term, but if you `D` is chosen excessively large some terms of your sum will be rounded to zero, which is less precise but definitely better than infinity.

Comment: +1. Since "d" comes from a uniform distribution, using `D=max(d)` is almost perfect. To be completely foolproof, you'd want to catch the bad cases where the v/u term happens to be very small in conjonction with "d" reaching its max.. To prevent that, use this:
`D <- max((v/u)^(1/a)*d)`

Comment: Thank you Victor and @FabienViger!