# Calculate exponential of sum of logs

Tags: r, exponent, exponentiation

In R, I have a vector of logged values (denoted `log_w`).

I need to calculate `sum(exp(log_w))` however due to the sizes of the values held in `log_w`, as soon as I exponentiate `log_w` I get a vector of zeros.

Example in R, showing a small vector of similar values:

```
    log_w<-c(-14781.5000092473, -1.68703503244454e+46, -4.24636436410052e+36, 
             -1.90459568391779e+30, -6565872478811.07, -1.58627856636904e+32, 
             -1.41504360955663e+84, -9.09553094112168e+52, -1.8247785275833e+40, 
             -10566415795189.4)
    exp(log_w)
    sum(exp(log_w))
```

I am aware of the LogSumExp (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp) to calcuate the log of a sum of exponentiated values, however I cannot see how this can be used to calculate the sum of a vector of exponentiated logged values.  Are there any other similar approximations that anyone could point me towards to calculate the sum of the exponential of logged values?  Any advice greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Further information - `log_w` are logged weights.  I need to be able to normalise the weights, i.e. calculate w/sum(w), however I currently only have the logged weights (log(w)).

EDIT

Using library Brobdingnag (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Brobdingnag/index.html) I can calculate `exp(log_w)` however using that package, `sum(exp(log_w))` results in `+exp(0)`

Comment: none of those numbers come even close to fitting in double precision once exponentiated... what are you hoping to accomplish exactly?

Comment: With a list of numbers like that, pick the largest and exponentiate that. The sum of the others will be a rounding error compared to the biggest.

Comment: I've added more information in the question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r

Comment: ...but even your biggest, -14781, [exponentiated is 4.9e-6420](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-14781%29). The next biggest is the -65658... and even Wolfram Alpha won't compute it. Setting the weight of the biggest to1 and the rest to 0 will be accurate to, probably, 20 decimal places.