# How to adjust the numerical precision for integers

Tags: python, r, biginteger

I'm trying to work with big numbers in R, in my opinion they aren't even that big. I asked R to return me the module of the division of 6001532020609003100 by 97, I got answer 1; when doing the same calculation in Python I got answer 66.

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R doesn't have the same kind of "magic", arbitrary-length integers that Python does: its base integer type is 32 bit, which maxes out at `.Machine$integer.max` == 2147483647. When confronted with a number greater than this value R automatically converts it to double-precision floating point; then the `%%` operator gets messed up by floating-point imprecision. (If you try to insist that the input is an integer by entering `6001532020609003100L` (`L` indicates integer) R still converts it to float, but warns you ...)

@JonSpring is right that you can do completely arbitrary-length integer computation (up to your computer's memory capability) with `Rmpfr`, but you can
also use the `bit64` package for 64-bit integers, which your example *just* fits into:

```r
library(bit64)
x <- as.integer64("6001532020609003100")
x %% 97
## [1] 66
```

But doubling this value puts you out of the integer-64 range: `2*x` gives an overflow error.

Honestly, if you want to do a lot of big-integer calculation I'd say that Python is more convenient ...

Comment: Thank you Ben! I finally understood what is going on. Grateful!
I just don't understand why R uses 32 yet and not 64, would it be a very abrupt change?

Comment: It actually would be a pretty huge change. The `bit64` package gives you fairly transparent access to 64-bit integers ...

Answer (score 2):

```
library(Rmpfr)
as.integer(mpfr("6001532020609003100") %% 97)

[1] 66
```

Comment: Adopted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r