# %in% on numeric values returns wrong result

Tags: r, hmisc

6969277959563657216 is not one of the following numbers, yet `%in%` returns `TRUE`.

```
6969277959563657216  %in% c(6972646901044805634,
                            6935914801507893250,
                            6930019021496532993,
                            6969277959563657217,
                            7005257783989764866)
[1] TRUE
```

Why is this?

Comment: Might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r

Comment: typecast to character before making the comparison, since this is a precision error

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that most computer programs work with a precision of approx. 16 digits, see FAQ [7.31 Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and the link therein. The interpretation here is of course: "Why does R think these numbers are equal".

Example:

```r
6969277959563657216 == 6969277959563657217
[1] TRUE
```

More about this also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) and several other places.

**Edit:** Here a SO posting about big integers [long/bigint/decimal equivalent datatype in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r)