# How to check if a float is a true number in c++?

Tags: c++

How to check if a float number is a true number? That is: it is not infinity, negative infinity, NaN ...

```
float f;
???
```

Comment: You mean functions like [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan)? That's C++11 but does the job.

Comment: Have you seen [std::isfinite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) and the related functions?

Comment: you mean a *real* number? Because a number is true if it's different from 0.0

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37730313/edit) your question to not use `...` and instead fully explain what aspects must be considered to meet your definition of _true_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simpler than `std::fpclassify()` is to use [`std::isfinite()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite)

> Determines if the given floating point number arg has finite value i.e. it is normal, subnormal or zero, but not infinite or NaN.

Answer (score 5):

[std::isnormal()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnormal) does what you want but it also checks for 0.0. So you might check that case extra:

```
float f;
bool isNumber = (std::isnormal(f) || f == 0.0);
```

Edit: as pointed out by  user2079303 `isnormal` also returns false for a [subnormal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number) which the OP probably does not want.

However, maybe [std::isfinite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) does the right thing.

```
float f;
bool isNumber = std::isfinite(f) ;
```

it returns `false` for `NaN` and `Inf`.

Comment: I don't think you want `&&` here.

Comment: Are you sure that subnormals are not "*true*" numbers for OP?

Comment: @user2079303 to be honest I didnt know what subnormal is until 5 seconds ago and I just ignored it ;) Seems like my answer is wrong then

Answer (score 2):

[std::fpclassify()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify) looks like what you are looking for.

> ```
> int fpclassify( float arg );
> int fpclassify( double arg );
> int fpclassify( long double arg );
> int fpclassify( Integral arg );
> ```
>
> **Return value**
>
> one of `FP_INFINITE`, `FP_NAN`, `FP_NORMAL`, `FP_SUBNORMAL`, `FP_ZERO` or implementation-defined type, specifying the category of `arg`.

Answer (score 1):

For C++11 and onwards, use `!std::isnan(f) && !std::isinf(f)` to test for a number being neither NaN nor infinity (positive or negative).

Pre-C++11 it's a bit more difficult, but you can still do it. If your platform uses IEEE754 for the `float` then you can use:

1. `f == f` will be `false` *only* for the NaN case.
2. Something of the form `f == f / 2` will be `true` *only* for infinity or a number close to zero, and you can trivially eliminate the latter case.

Boost (www.boost.org) also provides methods for pre C++11. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/fpclass.html

Comment: `isnan` returns false for `inf`

Comment: You should probably mention that the pre-c++11 methods are guaranteed by IEEE-754 but not by c++ standard.