# Size of numbers in float array have significant impact on performance - Why?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, exp

**UPDATE 2:**

I've switched to initializing all arrays with fixed numbers. Why is performance faster when using `modeDampingTermsExp`:

```
12625671
12285846
12819392
11179072
12272587
11722863
12648955
```

vs using `modeDampingTermsExp2` ?

```
1593620
1668170
1614495
1785965
1814576
1851797
1808568
1801945
```

It's about 10x faster.

*Full code*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int bufferWriteIndex = 0;
float curSample = 0;
float tIncr = 0.1f;

float modeGainsTimesModeShapes[25] = { -0.144338, -1.49012e-08, -4.3016e-09, 7.45058e-09, -0, -0.25, 
-1.49012e-08, 4.77374e-16, -7.45058e-09, 0, -0.288675, 0, 4.3016e-09, 3.55271e-15, -0, -0.25, 
1.49012e-08, -1.4512e-15, 7.45058e-09, 0, -0.144338, 1.49012e-08, -4.30159e-09, -7.45058e-09, -0 };

float modeDampingTermsString[5] = { -8.03847, -30, -60, -90, -111.962 };
float damping[5] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
float modeFrequenciesArr[5] = { 71419.1, 266564, 533137, 799710, 994855 };

float modeDampingTermsExp[5] = { 0.447604, 0.0497871, 0.00247875, 0.00012341, 1.37263e-05 };
float modeDampingTermsExp2[5] = { -0.803847, -3, -6, -9, -11.1962 };


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float subt = 0;
    int subWriteIndex = 0;
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    while (true) {

        curSample = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            //Slow version
            //damping[i] = damping[i] * modeDampingTermsExp2[i];

            //Fast version
            damping[i] = damping[i] * modeDampingTermsExp2[i];
            float cosT = 2 * damping[i];

            for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
                curSample += modeGainsTimesModeShapes[i * 5 + m] * cosT;

            }
        }

        //t += tIncr;
        bufferWriteIndex++;


        //measure calculations per second
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - now;
        if ((elapsed / std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) > 1000) {
            now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            int idx = bufferWriteIndex;
            cout << idx - subWriteIndex << endl;
            subWriteIndex = idx;
        }

    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I changed `tIncr` to `0.1f` to avoid a possible subnormal number as mentioned by @JaMit. I've also removed `t += tIncr;` from the calculation.

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int bufferWriteIndex = 0;
float curSample = 0;
float t = 0;
float tIncr = 0.1f;

float modeGainsTimesModeShapes[25] = { -0.144338, -1.49012e-08, -4.3016e-09, 7.45058e-09, -0, -0.25, 
-1.49012e-08, 4.77374e-16, -7.45058e-09, 0, -0.288675, 0, 4.3016e-09, 3.55271e-15, -0, -0.25, 
1.49012e-08, -1.4512e-15, 7.45058e-09, 0, -0.144338, 1.49012e-08, -4.30159e-09, -7.45058e-09, -0 };

float modeDampingTermsString[5] = { -8.03847, -30, -60, -90, -111.962 };
float damping[5] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
float modeFrequenciesArr[5] = { 71419.1, 266564, 533137, 799710, 994855 };
float modeDampingTermsExp[5];


int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    /*
    for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
        modeDampingTermsExp[m] = exp(modeDampingTermsString[m] * tIncr);
    }*/


    for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
        modeDampingTermsExp[m] = modeDampingTermsString[m] * tIncr;
    }


    //std::thread t1(audioStringSimCos);
    //t1.detach();
    float subt = 0;
    int subWriteIndex = 0;
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    while (true) {

        curSample = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            damping[i] = damping[i] * modeDampingTermsExp[i];
            float cosT = 2 * damping[i] * cos(t * modeFrequenciesArr[i]);

            for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
                curSample += modeGainsTimesModeShapes[i * 5 + m] * cosT;

            }
        }

        //t += tIncr;
        bufferWriteIndex++;


        //measure calculations per second
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - now;
        if ((elapsed / std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) > 1000) {
            now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            int idx = bufferWriteIndex;
            cout << idx - subWriteIndex << endl;
            subWriteIndex = idx;
        }

    }
}
```

Now it runs faster WITH the `exp` in the intialization?

Output with `exp`:

```
7632423
7516857
6855266
6251330
7040232
6784555
7169865
7638150
7403717
7626824
7408493
7722998
```

around 7 million/s, and without `exp`:

```
1229743
1193849
1069924
1426083
1472080
1484318
1503082
1462985
1433372
1357586
1483370
1491731
1526445
1516673
1517916
1522941
1523948
1506818
```

around 1.5 million. This is confusing to me.

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

It seems like the way I initialize `modeDampingTermsExp` in my small example has a huge impact on the performance of my calculations, where I access it. Here is my minimum, reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int bufferWriteIndex = 0;
float curSample = 0;
float t = 0;
float tIncr = 1.0f / 48000;

float modeGainsTimesModeShapes[25] = { -0.144338, -1.49012e-08, -4.3016e-09, 7.45058e-09, -0, -0.25, 
-1.49012e-08, 4.77374e-16, -7.45058e-09, 0, -0.288675, 0, 4.3016e-09, 3.55271e-15, -0, -0.25, 
1.49012e-08, -1.4512e-15, 7.45058e-09, 0, -0.144338, 1.49012e-08, -4.30159e-09, -7.45058e-09, -0 };

float modeDampingTermsString[5] = { -8.03847, -30, -60, -90, -111.962 };
float damping[5] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
float modeFrequenciesArr[5] = { 71419.1, 266564, 533137, 799710, 994855 };
float modeDampingTermsExp[5];


int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    /*
    for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
        modeDampingTermsExp[m] = exp(modeDampingTermsString[m] * tIncr);
    }*/


    for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
        modeDampingTermsExp[m] = modeDampingTermsString[m] * tIncr;
    }


    //std::thread t1(audioStringSimCos);
    //t1.detach();
    float subt = 0;
    int subWriteIndex = 0;
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    while (true) {

        curSample = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            damping[i] = damping[i] * modeDampingTermsExp[i];
            float cosT = 2 * damping[i] * cos(t * modeFrequenciesArr[i]);

            for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
                curSample += modeGainsTimesModeShapes[i * 5 + m] * cosT;

            }
        }

        t += tIncr;
        bufferWriteIndex++;


        //measure calculations per second
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - now;
        if ((elapsed / std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) > 1000) {
            now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            int idx = bufferWriteIndex;
            cout << idx - subWriteIndex << endl;
            subWriteIndex = idx;
        }
    }
}
```

When I initialize it like this

```
for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
    modeDampingTermsExp[m] = exp(modeDampingTermsString[m] * tIncr);
}
```

using the `exp` function, performance is about 10 times slower than like this:

```
for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
    modeDampingTermsExp[m] = modeDampingTermsString[m] * tIncr;
}
```

I measure the calculations per second unsing chrono right below the 2 nested for loops in the endless `while(true)` loop (snippet of the fulle example above):

```
//measure calculations per second
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - now;
        if ((elapsed / std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) > 1000) {
            now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            int idx = bufferWriteIndex;
            cout << idx - subWriteIndex << endl;
            subWriteIndex = idx;
        }
```

Using the `exp` function, my program gives the following output for example:

```
538108
356659
356227
383885
389902
390405
391748
391375
388910
383791
391691
```

it stays at around 390k.

Using the other initialization without it, I get the following output:

```
3145299
3049618
2519474
2755627
2846730
2824666
2893591
3119401
3492762
3366317
3470675
3505168
3492805
3523005
3432182
3561458
3580840
3576725
```

around 3 - 3.5 million "samples" per second.

Why does the way I initialize the `modeDampingTermsExp` array impact performance later in the code where I access it? What am I missing here?

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with the following flags:
/O2 /Oi /Ot /fp:fast

Thank you very much!

Comment: Global `now` does not seem to be used at all. Why `#include <atomic>`? The code is not _minimal_. Can you get rid of all unnecessary staff?

Comment: Not knowing why in detail, but `damping[i]` become 0 without `exp` and values around `1e-042` with `exp`. Multiplying by zero may be optimized.

Comment: You are taking the 48,000th root of a number. What is the result? Do you end up in the realm of [subnormals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number)? If so, [Why does changing 0.1f to 0 slow down performance by 10x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314534/why-does-changing-0-1f-to-0-slow-down-performance-by-10x/9314926#9314926) seems relevant.

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks!Ive updated my original question. Now performance is faster using ```exp```at initialization? Why.

Comment: @MikeCAT Im not sure what exactly you mean-maybe you can look at the update I've posted, but ```damping[i]``` shouldn't become very close to zero now.

Comment: I inserted `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) cout << damping[i] << " "; cout << endl;` after `cout << idx - subWriteIndex << endl;`. I got `2.8026e-045 1.#INF 1.#INF 1.#INF 1.#INF` with `modeDampingTermsExp2` and got `0 0 0 0 0` with `modeDampingTermsExp` from UPDATE 2 code. I'm using g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 on Windows.