# Return zero and Inf values in C

Tags: c, math, floating-point, infinity

I use C to do computation using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main() {
    float x = 3.104924e-33;
    int i = 6000, j = 1089;
    float value, value_inv;

    value = sqrt(x / ((float)i * j));
    value_inv = 1. / value;

    printf("value = %e\n", value);
    printf("value_inv = %e\n", value_inv);
}
```

We can see, in fact, `value = 2.18e-20`. This does not exceed the boundary of `float` data type in C. But why the computer gives me

```
value = 0.000000e+00
value_inv = inf
```

Does anybody know why it happens and how to solve this problem without changing data type to `double`?

Comment: `x = 3.104924e-33` and the limit of float is `e+-38`. So you divide `x` by `6.5e6` resulting in `5e-40` which does exceed the range of `float` before `sqrt()` is called.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `5e-40` is smaller than `FLT_MIN`, but maybe not `FLT_TRUE_MIN`.  If implementation supports sub-normals,  OP's `x/((float)i*j)` is non-zero.

Comment: Yes, I've looked on sub-normals somewhat like quantum-gravity....

Answer (score 4):

OP's `float` apparently does not support [sub-normals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number).  C allows non-support.

> Does anybody know why it happens and how to solve this problem without changing data type to double?

This may be a implementation detail or due to a compiler option.  Without changing to `double`, look to a different compiler or options.  Look at options concerning sub-normal support, precision used for intermediate calculation and optimization levels (which sometimes short edge change cases like this.)

---

On my machine which does handle sub-normals, using C11, `FLT_TRUE_MIN`, smallest non-zero `float` is smaller than `FLT_MIN`, the smallest *normal* non-zero `float`.

```
#include<float.h>
float xx = x/((float)i*j);
printf("xx = %e %e %e\n",xx, FLT_MIN, FLT_TRUE_MIN);
```

Output

```
xx = 4.751943e-40 1.175494e-38 1.401298e-45
```

In OP's case, without sub-normal support, `xx` became 0.0f and led to the undesired output.

---

Using `double` math will handle the small intermediate `float` values.

```
value = sqrt(x/(1.0*i*j));  // Form product with `double` math
value_inv = 1.0f/value;     // Here we can just use float math
printf("value = %e\n",value);
printf("value_inv = %e\n",value_inv);
```

Output

```
value = 2.179897e-20
value_inv = 4.587373e+19
```

Answer (score 1):

On my computer (Ryzen 2700X, x86_64) the results are:

```
value = 2.179897e-020
value_inv = 4.587373e+019
```

You can try `1.f` instead `1.` , which actually is a double:

```
value_inv = 1.f/value;
```

Comment: And `sqrtf()` instead of `sqrt()`.

Comment: @Shawn Using `sqrtf()` will not solve OP's issue if implementation does not support sub-normals.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Maybe not, but just like using .1f, it'll prevent some conversions from float to double and back.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your system hasn't support more digit for `float`.  On my system the output is:

```
value = 2.179895e-020
value_inv = 4.587376e+019
```

Comment: this doesn't add any more information than [Arseniy Karpenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64299441/995714) above. Did you read other answers before posting this?

Comment: This answer does report a different result than @Arseniy Karpenko. and that makes it  informative.  This answer appears to be on a system using `float` with sub-normals whereas Arseniy Karpenko result appears that the intermediate `float` calculation used `double` math - something allowed by C, even without explicit `double` code.  See `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by myself.
I should change `sqrt(x/((float)i*j))` to `sqrt((double)x/((double)i*j))`. After this, I can get correct result:

```
value = 2.179897e-20
value_inv = 4.587373e+19
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use `float` instead of `double` for such computations:

- `3.104924e-33` is a `double` constant, it gets converted to `float` upon assignment, with a potential loss of precision
- `sqrt` gets a `double` argument and returns a `double` value. Implicit conversions occur again with potential loss of precision.
- `1. / value` computes with the type `double` because `1.` has this type. `value` gets converted before the division and the result is converted to `float` to store to `value_inv`.
- `value` and `value_inv` are implicitly converted to `double` when passed to `printf`.

All these conversions may incur loss of precision or even truncation to `0.`. You should instead always use `double` unless there is a strong requirement to use `float`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double x = 3.104924e-33;
    int i = 6000, j = 1089;
    double value, value_inv;

    value = sqrt(x / ((double)i * j));
    value_inv = 1. / value;

    printf("value = %e\n", value);
    printf("value_inv = %e\n", value_inv);
    return 0;
}
```

If for some reason you are required to use `float`, be careful to avoid unneeded conversions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float x = 3.104924e-33F;
    int i = 6000, j = 1089;
    float value, value_inv;

    value = sqrtf(x / ((float)i * j));
    value_inv = 1.F / value;

    printf("value = %e\n", value);
    printf("value_inv = %e\n", value_inv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice the colorizer bug on the float constant `3.104924e-33F`: the `F` does not have the proper style, albeit `1.F` is correct.