# Why is initial value of exponent -1128 in deconstructing number in a sign, an integer coefficient, and an exponent?

Tags: javascript, numbers, theory

Background: I am reading "How Numbers Work" in the book How JavaScript Works by Douglas Crockford.

A number in JavaScript is represented as `number = sign * coefficient * (2 ** exponent)`. I understand this but then there is a function `deconstruct` to represent an integer using the `sign`, `coefficient`, and `exponent`.

In order to find the `exponent`, the initial value is taken as `-1128`

> which is the exponent of 'Number.MIN_VALUE' minus the number of bits in the significand minus the bonus bit.

```
function deconstruct(number) {
   // .....
   exponent = -1128;
   let reduction = coefficient;
   while (reduction !== 0) {
   // .....
}
```

Why is `exponent = -1128`? I did not get the reason for starting with this number, please help me in understanding this.

The complete [deconstruct function](https://github.com/douglascrockford/howjavascriptworks/blob/master/deconstruct.js) as mentioned in the book.

A similar question is asked [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/howjavascriptworks/issues/14) but I did not understand the answer.

Comment: In IEEE 754 math, the exponents are "biased" as described in what you're reading.

Comment: Do you understand what the three parts that he mentions in the comment, and their values, are?

Comment: @Bergi If I understood correct - first the number in JS is float64 with 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits and the rest are significant bits. A floating-point number is expressed as `number = sign * significand * base ** exponent`. In order to explain the 0.1 + 0.2 we are creating a function to find these parts but for integers. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, that's 64bit floating point numbers. But I meant specifically what are "*exponent of 'Number.MIN_VALUE'*", the "*number of bits in the significand*" and the "*bonus bit*"?

Comment: Also you need to consider that `Math.MIN_VALUE` is a [subnormal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number)

Comment: @Bergi No, I did not understand them. Can you help with the explanation?

Comment: 53 significand bits consists of the bonus bit.

Comment: Wow, it's been more obscure and tangled than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Crockford chose this value so that the resulting `coefficient` is always a 53-bit integer.

The `deconstruct` function determines the exponent by repeatedly dividing by two, and counting how long it takes to reach `0`. For the number `1`, which has an exponent of `0` (for a coefficient of `1.0`), it takes 1075 steps, so by starting at `-1075` and counting up we'd arrive at the exponent of `0`. However, to get the long coefficient, we want to arrive at an exponent of `-53`, so we have to start at `-1128` already.

Another way to put it: `Number.MIN_VALUE`, which is `1 * 2**-1074`, needs to be multiplied by 2 1074 times to arrive at 1, then some more times to get the long coefficient.

Notice there are multiple off-by-one mistakes to be made here:

- to get the value `1` (a 1-bit integer) as a 53-bit integer, we need an exponent of `-52` not `-53`
- the loop to compute the exponent overshoots by 1 as it reaches `0`
- of the 53 significant bits, only 52 bits are stored in the significand, there's a [hidden implicit `1` bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_bit) (for normal numbers)

And Crockford actually made one of them! If you check out the maths, 1074 (exponent of `MIN_VALUE`) + 52 (significand binary digits) + 1 ("bonus bit", whatever that refers to) amounts to 1127, not 1128. Calling the `deconstruct` function will return a `.coefficient` with 54 binary digits, which is one too many.

That said, I think even the goal is questionable. Having the coefficient, which is actually a fractional number starting with `1.…`, represented as an integer may be excused as a teaching device for the book. But it doesn't make  any sense to represent [subnormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) (whose coefficients are fractional numbers `0.…`) as numbers larger than 2<sup>52</sup>, with barely any significant digits.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi for the answer, it definitely cleared up a lot for me.