# why numpy's nextafter(0,inf) will raise err when flag under(flow) enabled?

Tags: python, numpy

```py
from numpy import nextafter,seterr
print(nextafter(0.,1.)) #5e-324
seterr(under="raise")
print(nextafter(0.,1.)) #FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in nextafter
```

I do not understand this will raise a FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in nextafter.
I test in c language, and c program not panick

Comment: Some notes: `np.multiply(sys.float_info.min, sys.float_info.epsilon) -> 5e-324`. The first valid step in terms of normal floats is `nextafter(sys.float_info.min, 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`help(numpy.seterr)` describes underflow as

> Underflow: result so close to zero that some precision was lost

This corresponds to the more precise description in [`man feenableexcept`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/feenableexcept):

> The underflow exception occurs when a result has to be represented as a floating-point number, but has smaller absolute value than the smallest positive normalized floating-point number (and would lose much accuracy when represented as a denormalized number)

Zero is not a denormalized number. The next higher or lower value after zero is denormalized. Therefore a floating point exception is raised if you enable it. See also: [What is a subnormal floating point number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number/53203428#53203428)

The following C code also signals a floating point exception:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fenv.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  double f = 0.;
  feenableexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW);
  f = nextafter(f, 1.);
  printf("%g\n", f);
}
```

If you want to skip over the subnormal values, go from zero straight to `numpy.finfo('f8').smallest_normal` (2.2250738585072014e-308)