# Java: Divide Float.MIN_NORMAL by 2, do not get 0.0f?

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754

I must be getting old:

On Oracle JDK 8:

```
class A {

   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      float f3 = Float.MIN_NORMAL;
      float f3e1 = f3/2.0f;
      System.out.println(f3 + " / 2 -> " + f3e1);
      float f3e2 = f3/4.0f;
      System.out.println(f3 + " / 4 -> " + f3e2);
   }
}
```

Result

```
1.17549435E-38 / 2 -> 5.877472E-39
1.17549435E-38 / 4 -> 2.938736E-39
```

How is that possible? Isn't the `Float.MIN_NORMAL` the smallest `Float` still different from `0.0` (a `Float` in Java being required to be [32-bit IEEE 754 floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), sadly without [exceptions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Exceptions.html) (WTF!), and [thus the *normal* is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Single_precision) ~1.17549E−38)?

In which case, the printed values must be `Double` or something else with more precision than `Float` ... but the values are declared as `float`.

Comment: You are confusing MIN_NORMAL with MIN_VALUE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728309/difference-between-double-min-normal-and-double-min-value

Comment: @Eran Uhhh... yeah

Comment: So do you agree this question can be closed as a duplicate of that question?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yes, that was embarrassingly easy.

Comment: MIN_NORMAL = 0x1.0p-126 = 1.175E-38; smaller values are < 1.0 (like 0.8) with p-126.
`Math.nextAfter(0.0F, 1.0)` is 1.e-45 so there are many subnormal numbers.